# How do I import OS Sites Layer into QGIS/PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, postgis-2.0, ordnance-survey, psycopg2

I've found the OS Translator II plugin which works perfectly for the Topology Layers, but it doesn't have an option to import OS Sites Layers.

How can I import this product into QGIS/PostGIS? I've tried naively importing the `gml.gz` file but it only gives the following fields.

- id
- geom
- gml_id
- toid
- version
- versionDate
- reasonForChange
- refToFunctionalSite
- accessType
- refToRoutingPoint
- natureOfAccess
- refToITNRoadNode
- itnRoadNodeVersionDate

Answers using the QGIS GUI or Python `psycopg2` are equally useful.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've managed to answer my own question.

I ended up using the Loader tool from Astun technology ([here](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader)).

I had a number of errors and problems getting set up - or at least I thought I did - but they turned out to be mainly caused by trying to put quotes around the file paths in `loader.config`. These weren't required, and were causing `loader.py` to try and parse non-existent files.